# Удалить строку в таблице

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте!

Есть таблица, в ней несколько рядов данных, у каждого ряда есть атрибут title с номером ряда в таблице, так же в этом ряду находится кнопка добавления ряда ниже:

```
<table class="data_sheet">
    <tr  class="headers">
        <td nowarp>№</td>
        <td nowarp>Изменить</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content" title="1">
         <td>
             <p>text</p>
         </td>
          <td>
             <p class="button" onclick="addPosition();" title="1"> Добавить </p>
          </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

После добавления ряда атрибут `onclick` меняется на `rmRequest`, данная функция должна удалить строку целиком при нажатии на кнопку.

Вопрос такой: как узнать, по какой именно кнопке было нажатие, чтобы удалить ряд?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вам пример кода: https://jsfiddle.net/zudjk8yt/1/
Вместо атрибута onClick лучше работать с классом.
На всякий случай приведу суть примера. На тот случай, если он пропадет с jsfiddle

```
$('.add-position').click(function(){
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
})
```

А в самой таблице убирается артибут onClick и вместо него к элементу, по которому будем кликать добавляем произвольный класс, который заюзаем в js. В данном случае это add-position.